# VLC not working on Linux Mint Mate 17.1

Tags: linux-mint, vlc, cvlc

After install 'linux mint 17.1 mate (32 bit)' I can play media files on VLC. but after restart Linux Mint my VLS is not working. But I can play video on built in 'Videos' player.

for this I again install 'linux mint mate 17.1' but same problem occours. vlc not working, also i try with SMPlayer. its not working too. but built in 'Videos' player working fine.
Why this problem occours? how to solve?

**vlc** command output

```
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
[0x92bd160] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x9346da8] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x9346da8] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x9346da8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind Command Line Interface initialized. Type help for help`
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear out your old VLC using synaptic package manager.
Now sign into Software Manager by pressing Menu and use 
Top left software manager and insert your password 
Search for VLC and press enter and allow linux to load it.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt install qt4
```

and all work

Comment: i do not get it